# Add new record to the table by click on the button in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

In my MS Access form I want to implement a separate button, that adds a new record to the table. In order to do that I added a button and attached to this button an event:

```vb
Private Sub btnAddRec_Click()
    Refresh
    With CodeContextObject
        On Error Resume Next
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            btnAddRec.Enabled = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Everything is OK when you just open the window and click the `btnAddRec` button, the problem is when you first of all perform the navigation through existed records and only after that click on this button. I got the runtime error:

> *2105: «You can't go to the specified record. You may be at the end of a recordset».*

How to solve the issue? I need to have ability to add the new record on click on specific button, no matter, have I walked or not walked through the records before.

Comment: What is CodeContextObject?

Comment: The `With` statement seems to be superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple form with a field call Description (and AutoNumber) and created a button with the code that follows click event. I filled it with a number of records and navigated through them, then clicked the addNewRec button. The form navigated to the new record without issues. I was also able to click the addNewRec button directly after opening the form successfully.

```vb
Private Sub btnAddRec_Click()
On Error GoTo Err1
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Exit Sub
Err1:
    Description.SetFocus
    btnAddRec.Enabled = False
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
End Sub
```

The differences from the code you included were removing the refresh and With statement, handing the error, setting focus before disabling the button and showing the user the error description. I do not know if your form is similar, but this should work for you if it is and I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: I tried your code and found out, that try to open the form, walk forward for some records and after that click on add button, I got the error.

Comment: This is very simple and this code works fine for me. If you are showing all the code in your form, this should work. Perhaps you should start over. Recreate the form and this time when you add the addNewRec button, from the Command Button Wizard, choose "Record Operations" and "Add New Record".